# An algorithm randomly generates a sequence $(c_1, c_2,... c_n)$

Tags: probability, statistics

An algorithm randomly generates a sequence $(c_1, c_2,... c_n)$, where each $c_i$ can assume the values $0$, $1$ or $2$. Given $A_k =$ {$k$ values of the sequence are equal to $0$} and $B_j$ = {$j$ values of the sequence are equal to $1$}.

How to calculate $P (A_k)$, for $k = 0, 1,. . . , n$?

Answer (score 0):

$A_k$ follows a binomial distribution where the probability of success $p = 1/3$ and the probability of failure is $q = 2/3$. Note that I am assuming that $c_i \sim U(3)$ iid. Thus
$$P(A_k)=\binom{n}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}.$$